# Angular Dark Theme

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Hello I have made a toggle button that changes my Ionic 3 app to dark mode. But I don't know where to define the global class `[class.dark-theme]="dark"`. It must be on app.component.ts to make the change in the whole app. This is what I have so far:

any-page.html

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>
      Dark Mode
    </ion-label>
    <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="dark"></ion-toggle>
  </ion-item>
```

variable.scss

```
.dark-theme
{
  ion-label{
    font-size: 33pt;
  }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
export class MyApp {
  dark=false;
}
```

How should I define the class for `NgModel="dark"` `([class.dark-theme]="dark")`

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a Dark Theme too, but with Angular and not Ionic. The purpose is to add a `dark` class into the body element.
I share with you my code :)

First, create a component dark-mode.component :

```js
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

export class DarkModeComponent implements OnInit {

  private class = 'dark';
  private storage = 'darkMode';

  @Input()
  get value(): boolean {
    return this.document.body.classList.contains(this.class);
  }

  set value(isDark: boolean) {
    localStorage.setItem(this.storage, isDark.toString());

    if (isDark) {
      this.document.body.classList.add(this.class);
    } else {
      this.document.body.classList.remove(this.class);
    }
  }

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const value = localStorage.getItem(this.storage);
    if (value) {
      this.value = JSON.parse(value);
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using local storage to keep the user's choice.
Here is the HTML (so complicated) :

```html
<span (click)="value = !value">Switch theme</span>
```

I've imported this component in my app.module.ts :

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
    DarkModeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [...],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then you just have to call your component in a HTML template, I put it into a menu.component.html:

```html
<dark-mode></dark-mode>
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks Emilien . Shouldn't be there a simpler way to define a class?adding it for whole app?

Comment: The setter in the DarkModeComponent do the stuff. Did you tried it ? this.document.body.classList.add(‘dark’)

Comment: Yes it works! But i want to do it by adding a global class ( dark-theme) in app.component file that will be triggered when dark in ngModel is true. The way i ve done it, works. But i can't figure out how to make the class apply fot the whole app and for a single page. E.g. if i put the class like this in a single page it works <ion-content class.dark-theme]="dark">.....</ion-content> Sorry if didn't make my problem clear

Comment: You may put <dark-mode></dark-mode> in any page?

Comment: @SimonIoa I don't see in your post where do you display the CSS class. I give you an answer which will give you the possibility to manage your themes with a global CSS class on body tag. I don't understand what you need more.

Comment: this is the class <ion-app [class.dark-theme]="dark"></ion-app> It works on Ionic 5 when you put it in app-component.html but not in ionic 3. I tried to put it in index.html but it doesnt work so i thought it would be nice to put a class in app.component.ts